# bash command to remove lines which are present in other text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am on bash I have two files added.txt and unmatched.txt , now imagine that all lines from added.txt are present in unmatched.txt . I want to remove lines from unmatched.txt which are present in added.txt . for example

1) added.txt

```
apple
ball
```

2) unmatched.txt

```
cat
dog
apple
rar
ball
```

3) required output.txt

```
cat
dog
rar
```

Comment: This is NOT clear at all, please do add 3 things in your post.1- Sample of input, 2- sample of expected output and 3rd- your efforts. Kindly EDIT your post and let us know then?

Comment: Thanks for adding samples in your question, kindly do add your efforts too in your question which you have put in order to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial to do with `grep`:

```
$ cat added.txt
cat
dog
$ cat unmatched.txt
aardvark
cat
dog
giraffe
civet cat
$ grep -F -vx -f added.txt unmatched.txt
aardvark
giraffe
civet cat
```

Prints just lines of `unmatched.txt` that don't exactly match lines of `added.txt` (`-v` inverts the usual meaning of `grep`).